# Convert byte into special character Java

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth, character

I want send any value via Bluetooth, by any i mean value 0-255, but I can't convert this value into a char in string. I tried few different ways, but without success.

```
int a= 240 ;
char z=(char)a;
mConnectedThread.write("START"+"\240"+","+"\0240"+","+"\030"+","+Integer.toString(a)+","+z+","+"\0f1"+"STOP");
```

I get this (left - value in decimal, right value in ASCII char):

- 83-'S'
- 84-'T'
- 65- 'A'
- 82- 'R'
- 84- 'T'
- 194-'Â'
- 160- ''
- 44- ','
- 20-'\024'
- 48-'0'
- 44-','
- 24-'\030'
- 44-','
- 50-'2'
- 52-'4'
- 48-'0'
- 44-','
- 195-'Ã'
- 176-'°'
- 44 ','
- 0-'\0'
- 102-'f'
- 49-'1'
- 83-'S'
- 84-'T'
- 79-'O'
- 80-'P'

When I send `\030` then I receive `24-'\30'` in one character, but I can't send bigger numbers.

So my question is: how to set/convert any value in the range 0-255 in one string character. I don't need to display this, it's not important.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, Java characters aren't always one byte (a byte is always one byte). I think you just need to encode your characters, or use a `byte[]`.

Comment: How are you converting your byte array received via bluetooth to a string?

Comment: i don't need convert this data, becourse it's only: command +a lot value (0-255) + end command, but when i want convetr into string i use somthing like this (not exacly):[link](http://example.com) `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);  
      byte[] newbuffer = new byte[bytes];for(int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                      newbuffer[i] = buffer[i];
                     final String data = new String(newbuffer, "US-ASCII");`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

If you just want to write a string to the stream without converting it to bytes, you can use BufferedWriter :

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bufferedWriter.write("some string");
```

Make sure that you understand flush and close methods from the api:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

This is very standard in java to wrap the low level input/output stream objects with higher level Reader/Writer object to get access to more convenient methods.

**Original answer**

You can construct String using specific charset to decode bytes :
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.nio.charset.Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

US-ASCII could be enough for your use case
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

So you can construct a string out of byte array like this :

```
new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Answer (score 0):

I receive and send byte[] data, and it working good, but i think that makin this on string will be better, bocouse when i make data table it's looks like this

```
byte[] dat = new byte[50];
        dat[i++] = (byte) '!';
        dat[i++] = (byte) '!';
        dat[i++] = (byte) 0xf0;
        dat[i++] = (byte) 0xf0;
        dat[i++] = (byte) SET_COUPLING;
        dat[i++] = (byte) (coupling + 64*this.name);
        dat[i++] = (byte) 0xf0;
        dat[i++] = (byte) 0xf0;
        dat[i++] = (byte)SET_MULTI;
```

i just looking for better way to construct this command.
My send function :

```
void write(String str)
{
    if (STATE != CONNECTED)
        return;
    try
    {
        mmOutStream.write(str.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        synchronized (MainActivity.this)
        {
            btDisconnect();
            changeState(CONNECTION_ERROR);
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

or second write function using byte[]:

```
void write(byte[] data)
{
    if (STATE != CONNECTED)
        return;

    try
    {
        mmOutStream.write(data);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                btDisconnect();
                changeState(CONNECTION_ERROR);
                mConnectedThread = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i see that i convert this string into byte[] using **mmOutStream.write(str.getBytes());**, but i was thinking that making string command and then convert int byte[] is more elegant method.
I thought that is simple way to make this like in sprintf

```
sprintf(str,"%4.1f\xdf""C", temp);
```

where "\xdf" is just 223 in one byte and is degree mark when i put this into alphanumeric display